# Find the UMVUE of $H(\theta)$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation, order-statistics

I've been working on the following problem:

> Let $h(\cdot)$ be a given function that is strictly positive, finite and continuous on the real line and define $H(x)=\int_0^xh(y)dy$. Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be a random sample from the distribution whose pdf is given by $f(x\mid\theta)=c(\theta)h(x)I_{(0<x<\theta)}$.
>
> (a) Compute MLE of $\theta$; (b) Find a sufficient and complete statistic for $\theta$ and denote is by $S$; (c) Find an UMVUE of $H(\theta)$.

In my solution I found that $\hat{\theta}_{MLE}=X_{(n)}$ and that $S=X_{(n)}$.
I am not sure how to go about point c. Any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [Lehmann-Scheffe Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmann%E2%80%93Scheff%C3%A9_theorem), the UMVUE is an a.s. unique function of the complete sufficient statistic, $X_{(n)}$. Here are some parts of the puzzle that you will need to piece together:

1) The density of $X_{(n)}$ is given by 
$$g(x|\theta) = n[c(\theta)]^nH(x)^{n-1}h(x), \;\;\; 0 < x < \theta $$

2) $H(\theta) = \dfrac{1}{c(\theta)}$

3) $E[H(X_{(n)})] = a_nH(\theta)$, where $a_n$ is a constant depending ONLY on $n$, and not $\theta$. You can calculate $a_n$ quite easily.

By Lehmann-Scheffe, you can conclude that $T = \dfrac{1}{a_n}H(X_{(n)})$ is the UMVUE.

Comment: This makes sense. I just wonder how did you know to use $H(X_{(n)})$ to compute an unbiased estimator?

Comment: That was more of a trial an error. In general, if I want to find an unbiased estimator of $f(\theta)$, where $f$ is complicated like above, my first instinct is to try $f(S)$ where $S$ is a complete sufficient statistic.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: This Problem has an other question: Find $E{H(X_1)|S}$ where S is a complete and sufficient statistic. I thought I would be able to solve it without help but wasn't successful. Would you have any insight?

Comment: You can show that $2H(X_1)$ is unbiased for $H(\theta)$. So by Lehmann-Scheffe, $E[2H(X_1)| S]$ is the UMVUE. But we already found what the UMVUE is. So by uniqueness, we can conclude that....?

Comment: That they must be the same! Thank you so much!!